# Joomla form validation ignoring password fields

Tags: forms, validation, joomla

I want to make a client side form validation.

I´ve followed the instrucktions on https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

when I press submit, I get a system message without text and it won't submit even though everything is made correct in the inputs.

```
<?php 
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die; 
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.formvalidator.setHandler('passverify', function (value) {
        return (jQuery('input[type=password]').value == value); 
    });
});
</script>

<form class="form-validate" method="post" name="shout" onSubmit="submitbutton">

    <label>Navn</label><input class="inputbox required" name="LicensForm[name]" type="text" /><br/>
    <label>Bruger navn</label><input class="inputbox required validate-username" name="LicensForm[username]" type="text" /><br/>
    <label>Password</label><input id="password" class="inputbox required validate-password" name="LicensForm[password]" type="password" /><br/>
    <label>Bekræft password</label><input id="password2" class="inputbox required validate-passverify" name="LicensForm[password2]" type="password" /><br/>
    <label>Email</label><input class="inputbox required validate-email" name="LicensForm[email]" type="text" /><br/>

    <label>Indløs licensnøgle</label><input class="inputbox required" name="LicensForm[licens]" type="text" /><br/>

    <input class="validate" type="submit" name="submit" value="check licensnøgle"/>
</form>
```

[image: screenshot of form and system message]

Comment: I guess it is because your `password2` field also has the validate-password class. If that is called after your `validate-passverify` class the field will return true after being false. Which would lead to an invalid field and an authorised submit after. That's the only thing I can think of. Rest looks fine. So take out that class.

Comment: Thanks! @HansWassink good suggestion!... Didn't work though.. But then I saw I was missing the "validate" class on the submit button... But now I'm getting a system alert without text in it when I submit and it won't even submit if im typing every field correct... see updated description

Comment: Is jQuery defined? If not: try adding `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` at the top of your page under the `defined` line. Because if it isn't your `return (jQuery('input[type=password]').value == value); ` will never return true.

- If that's not working try changing your return statement into:
`return (jQuery('input#password').value == value);`. Last suggestion is checking the console.log of your browser for js errors.

Comment: Thanks @HansWassink! I can´t get it to work though... In the mean time, I´ve switched to a solution using html5 validation. So I think I´ll just leave it here and stick with the html5 :) Thanks for the good suggestions!

Comment: Too bad man, but every modern browser has the html5 validation anyways :) Good luck!

Comment: @HansWassink Thanks! and yes, thats way I don´t want to fight any more on the Joomla validation, because the html5 even works and looks better :)

Comment: Why are you doing anything besides what is done in the core?  YOu do not want to rely on JS validation for something like a password or really anything serious.   It's okay as a quick test but not enough.  So you need to  check that the two passwords match, that's the point of password validation, in addition to limiting the length the avoid an overflow attack.

Comment: Hi @Elin thanks for your message! :) the input is checked in the server side too though. I’m adding it as a new user, so joomla takes care of checking if the passwords match ect. :)

Comment: Okay I don't understand your question at all then. What is it that you are trying to do?  How is it that you think it is not working exactly as designed? All built in Joomla fields are HTML5.

Comment: @Elin When I use the code above, Joomla won’t submit it even though every think is correct written in the form fields. It just marks the 2nd password filed red and the error message is empty. In the html of the error message it’s just an empty html tag like <p></p>

Comment: So you are NOT asking how to create the field just why it is not working?  I would go ask on the Joomla stackexchange site, [joomla.se].

Comment: @Elin Oh! Thanks Elin, did’t know that one 